# Need to calculate percentage of total count of product in SQL Query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have three columns country companyid and product I have to calculate percent and count of product by country wise

Data is like this

```
country companyid product     
-------------------------    
usa     101       phone       
usa     101       Trimmer     
usa     102       ipad        
usa     102       trimmer     
usa     102       phone       
usa     105       trimmer     
india   104       ipad
india   104       phone
india   103       phone
india   103       trimmer
```

I want output of pct like this divided by 5 not divided by overall count that is 10

```
country product count  pct
------------------------------
usa     phone     2    2/5*100
usa     trimmer   2    2/5*100
usa     ipad      1    1/5*100
india   phone     2    2/5*100
india   trimmer   2    2/5*100
india   ipad      1    1/5*100
```

Let me known how can I do it.

Comment: Show us **YOUR efforts** first! Try something, if you get stuck - come back and show what you've tried, and where you're stuck...

Comment: possible duplicate of [OVER() clause. When and why is it useful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218902/over-clause-when-and-why-is-it-useful)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT T.COUNTRY, T.PRODUCT, COUNT(T.PRODUCT) COUNT, (COUNT(T.PRODUCT)/5*100) PCT FROM TABLE_NAME T GROUP BY T.PRODUCT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the count by using OVER(PARTITION BY)

```
SELECT DISTINCT country ,product,
COUNT(product) OVER(PARTITION BY country ,product) AS [COUNT],
CAST(COUNT(product) OVER(PARTITION BY country ,product)AS VARCHAR(10))+'/5*100' AS pct
FROM YOURTABLE
order by country desc
```

- **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6f807/1)**