# SQL select top rows based on limit

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

Please help me t make below select query

Source table

```
name Amount  
 -----------
 A   2    
 B   3    
 C   2
 D   7
```

if limit is 5 then result table should be

```
name Amount  
 -----------
 A   2    
 B   3
```

if limit is 8 then result table

```
name Amount  
 -----------
 A   2    
 B   3    
 C   2
```

Comment: Which version of sql server you are using

Comment: Why is *C* excluded if limit is 5?

Comment: Is your limit is based on Total of the amount and not on number of records?

Comment: limit is based on total amount, we are using sql server 2014

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use window function to achieve this:

```
select name,
    amount
from (
    select t.*,
        sum(amount) over (
            order by name
            ) s
    from your_table t
    ) t
where s <= 8;
```

The analytic function `sum` will be aggregated row-by-row based on the given order `order by name`.

Once you found sum till given row using this, you can filter the result using a simple where clause to find rows till which sum of amount is under or equal to the given limit.

---

More on this topic:

- [The SQL OVER() clause - when and why is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218902/the-sql-over-clause-when-and-why-is-it-useful)
- https://explainextended.com/2009/03/08/analytic-functions-sum-avg-row_number/

Comment: @JonathanPorter Updated with some explanation.

Comment: Much appreciated.