# Return Min Start Date, Max End Date and Latest Category for a group of consecutive records based on date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which contains a Person ID, Category_ID, Start Date, End Date and Category.  When the Start Date is the same as the Previous End Date then this is a continuation and merely denotes a Category Change.  There can be many Category changes within a continuous date period.

I want to return the First Start Date and Last End Date and Category Type for each person.

I thought about identifying all those that have continuous date period for a person and return max and min etc.  But this doesn't take into account when a person has multiple continuous date periods, i.e. one period ends and there is a break and then there is another continuous period with category changes.

Example output:

```
+---------+------------+------------+---------------+
|   ID    |  start_dt  |   end_dt   | category_type |
+---------+------------+------------+---------------+
| 8105755 | 26/01/2016 | 21/04/2016 | D             |
| 8105859 | 21/04/2016 | 22/04/2016 | A             |
| 8105861 | 22/04/2016 | 26/04/2016 | D             |
| 8105870 | 26/04/2016 | 19/10/2016 | A             |
+---------+------------+------------+---------------+
```

So in this case as the end_dt is the same as the preceding start_dt for each row this is a continuous period so I want to return one row with the First Start Date and Last End Date and Latest Category Type, as below:

```
+---------+------------+------------+---------------+
|   ID    |  start_dt  |   end_dt   | category_type |
+---------+------------+------------+---------------+
| 8105870 | 26/01/2016 | 19/10/2016 | A             |
+---------+------------+------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Can you include more sample data and the expected output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The SQL OVER() clause - when and why is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218902/the-sql-over-clause-when-and-why-is-it-useful)

Answer (score 0):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem, which you can solve using a cumulative sum to identify the groups.  The sum is based on when groups start.  So:

```
select distinct
       first_value(t.id) over (partition by grp order by t.start_dt desc) as id,
       min(t.start_dt) over (partition by grp) as start_dt,
       max(t.start_dt) over (partition by grp) as end_dt,
       first_value(t.category) over (partition by grp order by t.start_dt desc) as id
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when t.id is null then 1 else 0 end) over (order by t.start_dt) as grp
      from t left join
           t tprev
           on tprev.end_dt = t.start_dt
     ) t;
```

Note:  This uses `select distinct` simply because SQL Server does not offer "first()"/"last()" functions for aggregation.